# Python How to store decoded unicode string from email in list and then use later?

Tags: python, email, unicode, encoding

I have been working on parsing emails with Python. Learning how to handle character encoding has been challenging. I am using the native email libraries to create a msg object.

I first take the important header values and store as variables. No problem here as far as I can tell. This is an example of getting the subject. Other header values are aquired in a similar way.

```
try:
    subject_parts = decode_header(subject_var)
    fixedsubjectLine = ' '.join(abytes.decode('raw-unicode-escape' if enc == None else enc) for (abytes, enc) in subject_parts)
except:
    fixedsubjectLine = "Subject Failed to Parse"
    print "ERROR"
```

I then walk through the parts of the email the get the body and attachments.
I write the payload parts to disk.
Some of the emails parsed have Chinese characters and are encoded.
To write the file with the correct characters, I take the filename and encode it to its encoding as indicated by the payload encoding.

```
# get charecter encoding
char_set = part.get_content_charset()

# get the filename of the msg part, if it exist.
filename = part.get_filename() 
if decode_header(filename)[0][1] is not None:
    passed_filename = str(decode_header(filename)[0][0]).decode(decode_header(filename)[0][1])


# If there is a charecter set for the current email part
if char_set:
    filename = passed_filename.encode(char_set)
else:
    char_set = 'utf-8'
    filename = passed_filename.encode('utf-8')

try:
    filename = filename.replace("/","")
    logger.info(chardet.detect(filename))
    fp = open(os.path.join(tmpDir,filename), 'wb+')
    fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
    fp.close()
except:
    print "ERROR"
```

For each iteration of the msg.walk() function I append the values in a dict to a list.

```
email_parts.append ({"msg" : (os.path.join(tmpDir, filename)), "subject" : fixedsubjectLine, "from" : fixedfromAdd, "to" : fixedtoAdd, "sent" : timestamp ,"encoding" : char_set})
```

Prior to adding to the list, I check the encoding of the filename, and print it to a log file with the logging library.

```
{'confidence': 0.99, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}
 的质量投诉 客服审核中.xlsm
```

I then write the list to a file, like below.

```
try:
    emailPartsFile = os.path.join(tmpDir, 'email_parts.txt')
    f = open(emailPartsFile,'w')
    for item in email_parts:
        f.write(str({"msg" : item['msg'], "subject" : item['subject'], "from" : item['from'], "to" : item['to'], "sent" : item['sent'] ,"encoding" : item['encoding']}))
        f.write('\n') 

    f.close()
    os.chmod(emailPartsFile, 0755)    
    os.chown(emailPartsFile,1000,1000)     
    return emailPartsFile
except:
    print "ERROR"
```

This gives me a file with the following format. In this log, you can see 2 parts of the email that are manually created from the email content, and then a file attachment. This is the filename above (的质量投诉 客服审核中.xlsm)

```
{'from': u'john smith <johnsmith@gmail.com>', 'encoding': 'utf-8', 'to': 'johnsmith@mailserver.com', 'msg': 'part-001.html', 'sent': 'Thu, 09 May 2016 01:48:24 -0000', 'subject': u'Fwd: \u7684\u8d28\u91cf\u6295\u8bc9 \u5ba2\u670d\u5ba1\u6838\u4e2d'}
{'from': u'john smith <johnsmith@gmail.com>', 'encoding': 'utf-8', 'to': 'johnsmith@mailserver.com', 'msg': 'part-002.html', 'sent': 'Thu, 09 May 2016 01:48:24 -0000', 'subject': u'Fwd: \u7684\u8d28\u91cf\u6295\u8bc9 \u5ba2\u670d\u5ba1\u6838\u4e2d'}
{'from': u'john smith <johnsmith@gmail.com>', 'encoding': 'utf-8', 'to': 'johnsmith@mailserver.com', 'msg': '\xe7\x9a\x84\xe8\xb4\xa8\xe9\x87\x8f\xe6\x8a\x95\xe8\xaf\x89 \xe5\xae\xa2\xe6\x9c\x8d\xe5\xae\xa1\xe6\xa0\xb8\xe4\xb8\xad.xlsm', 'sent': 'Thu, 09 May 2016 01:48:24 -0000', 'subject': u'Fwd: \u7684\u8d28\u91cf\u6295\u8bc9 \u5ba2\u670d\u5ba1\u6838\u4e2d'}
```

When writing the filename to disk, is is decoded correctly, and the file name retains the correct Chinese charecters.

The problem is that, as you can see the text is still encoded for the filename and header values in the text file.

To troubleshoot, I have written these values to a file with the logging library:

```
from logging.handlers import SysLogHandler
logger.info('|filename:'+tmpDir + '|Email_TIMESTAMP:'+sentTime + '|Created_TIMESTAMP:'+timestamp + '|TO:'+fixedtoAdd + '|FROM:'+fixedfromAdd + '|SUBJECT:' + fixedsubjectLine + '|'+ char_set+ '|')
```

When writing to the log file, the values also appear correctly decoded.
The problem only seems to be when I directly write the list to the file.
I have also tried with a simple print statement, and it prints correctly.

Ideally, I would like to write the Chinese characters to the file.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you write to the file, use the following:

```
f = open(emailPartsFile,'wb')
```

....

```
f.write(str(<YOUR_DICT>).encode('utf8'))
```

When you open your file, it should have the Chinese characters.

Comment: When you open the file, or in your terminal?

Comment: Both. I can cat the file and also edit it with vi or nano. Same results.
`\xe7\x9a\x84\xe8\xb4\xa8\xe9\x87\x8f\xe6\x8a\x95\xe8\xaf\x89 \xe5\xae\xa2\xe6\x9c\x8d\xe5\xae\xa1\xe6\xa0\xb8\xe4\xb8\xad.xlsm`

Comment: So, the Chinese characters are showing up in your terminal when you look at the filenames, but they are not showing up inside that files themselves?

Comment: Correct. In the code above, I write the attachment to disk, and write it with the same filename variable that I later use to add to the list. 
The attachment on disk has the correct Chinese name, but the list content written to another file does not.